# What is this url string concept called?

Tags: url, query-string

I have just been on a [website](http://www.holidaysplease.co.uk/holiday-finder/#%7B%22d%22:%222016-06-1%22,%22a%22:[],%22t%22:20,%22r%22:200,%22f%22:13,%22tr%22:180,%22s%22:[5,4,3],%22ac%22:[],%22c%22:[],%22sh%22:[],%22dh%22:[],%22du%22:null,%22b%22:%22500-4407%22%7D) and I noticed they have a strange query string structure in the URL, they seem to be key value pairs and when you make a change in the website form the values update in the URL.

Here is the URL:

```
http://www.holidaysplease.co.uk/holiday-finder/#{"d":"2016-06-1","a":[],"t":20,"r":200,"f":13,"tr":180,"s":[5,4,3],"ac":[],"c":[],"sh":[],"dh":[],"du":null,"b":"500-4407"}
```

Does anyone know what this concept is called? I recall seeing it once in a Java based web application but can someone reassure me how this is achieved and in what language?

Comment: It's in the hash part so it deals with JavaScript code...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a fragment identifier.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier):
The fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark # is the optional last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document. The generic syntax is specified in RFC 3986. The hash mark separator in URIs does not belong to the fragment identifier.

RFC 3986 is defined [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

Before, I never saw that before. The upper information is what a little bit of research gave me back. I hope this is not completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The text after a `#` in a URL is a fragment identifier, which is normally used to refer to a section in the document, but can contain any data which won't be sent in the request to the server, but can be read by the client using JavaScript.

In your example, the fragment identifier contains a data structure encoded with [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), which is a serialization format supporting key-value pairs and arrays.

Here's the JSON from your example in a more readable form:

```
{
    "d": "2016-06-1",
    "a": [],
    "t": 20,
    "r": 200,
    "f": 13,
    "tr": 180,
    "s": [
        5,
        4,
        3
    ],
    "ac": [],
    "c": [],
    "sh": [],
    "dh": [],
    "du": null,
    "b": "500-4407"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind this is the data which the user entered is send to the server as the `JSON structure` in the URL. The server reads the string as a JSON and it process the request.

This process is very effective in `WebForm` and it can be done using the method called `encodeURIComponent`.

I think you noticed that when the date is changed, it just update the JSON in the URL. So, they send the data filled to the server in a JSON format.

In your URL,

```
d - days and year
du - duration
a - holiday type
t - temperature
r - rainfall
f- fight time
tr - travel
s - star for the hotels
b - budgets
```

Hope this information helps you :)

Comment: So how exactly is this JSON data send to the server?

Comment: They will keep track on the url when the user fills the form and when the user filled every field, the server will check for the JSON and they will proceed the operation with that JSON data. If you noticed in the site, when you filled every field, the data (i.e., hotels) will be listed below in the form. So, thats how it works :)

Comment: Fragment identifiers aren't sent to the server.  They're processed by the client.

Comment: But surely it needs to be processed at server side with some AJAX call as it brings back data from the database?

Answer (score 0):

The part after the `#` is called a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). Client-side javascript code can access the content of the fragment using `location.hash`. In this case the fragment contains json data. The browser will typically not even send the fragment to the web server, so it's only used client-side.

The most common use of the fragment identifier is to link to a specific element on a web page using it's `id` attribute. This is used for subsections of wikipedia articles:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Basics
```

When the fragment contains json, you can inspect the data by opening up your browser's javascript console and calling this code.

```
JSON.parse(location.hash.substr(1))
```

This kind of scheme can be used by single page applications to store state in the url, so that you can bookmark it and share the url.